# Java riddle: static binding

Tags: java, class, binding, static-methods

I'm given Class `C` and interface `A` and I'm not allowed to do any changes in them. I should write class `B` so that the code will always output `success!`

There is two things that I don't understand in the code of class `C` inside the for loop.

1) I don't understand which bar method is called.

2) when return is reached where does it return to?

Should I change the implementation of `B` in order to get it to work?

```
public interface A {

    public String bar();
}



public class C extends B {

    public int foo = 100;

    public C(String s) {
        super(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void barbar() {
        foo++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = args[0];
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(input);
        C c = new C(input); //c=args[0]
        B b = c; //b=args[0]
        A a = b; //a=args[0]

        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            if (!builder.toString().equals(a.bar())) { //which bar is called?
                return; //where does it return to? does it exist the for loop?
            }
            builder.append(input);
            c.foo++;
        }

        if (c.foo - 99 == b.foo.length() / input.length()) {
            System.out.println("success!");
        }
    }
}


public class B implements A {



    public String foo;

    public B(String s) {
        this.foo=s;
    }

    public void barbar() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public String bar() {
        return this.foo;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `bar()` defined in `class B` is called ofcourse. If you believe that method from `interface A` is called, I must tell you that methods from an interface are never **CALLED**. As Interfaces have only method declarations(unless it's a `default` method) that an implementing non-abstract class has to define. And the line `return this.foo` is executed.
2. `return` statement from the `main` method ends the program. It returns to the JVM, which in turn returns to the OS.